# How to refactor three methods with the same logic?

Tags: java, collections, refactoring, future

Here are my methods:

```
    public List<Task> stopAndUpdateTasks(Map<Long, Future<Task>> futuresTask, List<Task> oldTasks, Map<Long, TaskStatus> oldTasksStatuses) {
        futuresTask.values().forEach(f -> f.cancel(false));
        final Map<Long, Task> tasksToUpdate = oldTasks.stream()
                .filter(task -> futuresTask.get(task.getId()).isCancelled())
                .peek(task -> task.setStatus(oldTasksStatuses.get(task.getId())))
                .collect(toMap(Task::getId, task -> task));
        log.info("Interrupted tasks ids:" + tasksToUpdate.keySet());
        return new ArrayList<>(tasksToUpdate.values());
    }

    public List<PayProcess> stopAndUpdateProcesses(Map<Long, Future<PayProcess>> futures, List<PayProcess> oldProcesses, Map<Long, ProcessingStatus> processesWithStatus) {
        futures.values().forEach(f -> f.cancel(false));
        final Map<Long, PayProcess> processesToUpdate = oldProcesses.stream()
                .filter(PayProcess -> futures.get(PayProcess.getId()).isCancelled())
                .peek(payProcess -> payProcess.setProcessingStatus(processesWithStatus.get(payProcess.getId())))
                .collect(toMap(PayProcess::getId, payProcess -> payProcess));
        log.info("Interrupted payments ids:" + processesToUpdate.keySet());
        return new ArrayList<>(processesToUpdate.values());
    }

    private List<Bundle> stopAndUpdateBundles(Map<Long, Future<Bundle>> futureBundles, List<Bundle> oldBundles, Map<Long, BundleStatus> oldBundleStatuses) {
        futureBundles.values().forEach(f -> f.cancel(false));
        final Map<Long, Bundle> bundlesToUpdate = oldBundles.stream()
                .filter(task -> futureBundles.get(task.getId()).isCancelled())
                .peek(bundle -> bundle.setStatus(oldBundleStatuses.get(bundle.getId())))
                .collect(toMap(Bundle::getId, bundle -> bundle));
        log.info("Interrupted bundles ids:" + bundlesToUpdate.keySet());
        return new ArrayList<>(bundlesToUpdate.values());
    }
```

Can you suggest me something realy cool to refactor the methods? I can't imagine how to, but I have to do it. I tried to write generics and interfaces for the entities, but they don't work for Future

Here is my way to solve it:
[image]

As you can see - the entity impements required interface, but it doesn't work
[image]

Comment: Do `Bundle`, `PayProcess` and `Task`  have a common super class / implement the same interface?

Comment: @luk2302 it's possible to do it, but when I try to write a method with List<Future<? extends SuperClass>> my IDE says that it's not possible to use parametrization this way

Comment: @luk2302 Just added two screenshots with my problem

Comment: @МаксимРыбалкин added a soln. Please check. Does Task,PayProcess,Bundle all implement ScheduledEntity ? If yes, Then ScheduledEntity is exactly what my CommonSuperClass is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way (instead of using Wildcard generics). Note- this  assumes Task,Bundle and PayProcess have no existing common superclass.

Create an abstract superclass:

```
public abstract class CommonSuperClass<T>{

  private Long id;
  private T status;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public T getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(T status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

Now make Task ,PayProcess and Bundle extend it:

```
public class Task extends CommonSuperClass<TaskStatus>{
...
}
```

```
public class PayProcess extends CommonSuperClass<ProcessingStatus>{
...
}
```

Now define your method like this:

```
  public static <T extends CommonSuperClass<U>, U> List<T> stopAndUpdate(Map<Long, Future<T>> futures,
                                                                              List<T> oldList,
                                                                              Map<Long, U> oldStatuses) {
    futures.values().forEach(f -> f.cancel(false));
    final Map<Long, T> updates = oldList.stream()
        .filter(t -> futures.get(t.getId()).isCancelled())
        .peek(task -> task.setStatus(oldStatuses.get(task.getId())))
        .collect(toMap(t -> t.getId(), Function.identity()));
    //log.info("Interrupted tasks ids:" + tasksToUpdate.keySet());
    return new ArrayList(updates.values());
  }
```

With this you can use like:

```
    Map<Long, Future<Task>> futuresTask = new HashMap<>();
    List<Task> oldTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Long, TaskStatus> oldTasksStatuses = new HashMap<>();

    stopAndUpdate(futuresTask, oldTasks, oldTasksStatuses);

    Map<Long, Future<PayProcess>> futures = new HashMap<>();
    List<PayProcess> oldProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Long, ProcessingStatus> processesWithStatus = new HashMap<>();

    stopAndUpdate(futures, oldProcesses, processesWithStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you already have this relations or you can somehow change your code to do this

```
private List<Item> stopAndUpdate(Map<Long, Future<Item>> futureItems, List<Item> oldItems, Map<Long, Status> oldStatuses) {
    futureItems.values().forEach(f -> f.cancel(false));
    final Map<Long, Item> itemsToUpdate = oldItems.stream()
            .filter(task -> futureItems.get(task.getId()).isCancelled())
            .peek(item -> item.setStatus(oldStatuses.get(item.getId())))
            .collect(toMap(Item::getId, item -> item));
    log.info("Interrupted bundles ids:" + itemsToUpdate.keySet());
    return new ArrayList<>(itemsToUpdate.values());
}
```

Relations required

```
interface Item {
    Long getId();
    void setStatus(Status status);
}

interface Status {

}

class Task implements Item {
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status) {

    }
}

class PayProcess implements Item {
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status) {

    }

    public void setProcessingStatus(Status status) {
    }
}

class Bundle implements Item {
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status) {

    }
}

class TaskStatus implements Status{}

class ProcessingStatus implements Status{}

class BundleStatus implements Status{}
```

Comment: I am not sure how is this going to work? Task has it's own status called TaskStatus, similarly PayProcess and Bundle have their own status types. Do they all extend some common class Status?